# Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed on Mac

Tags: macos, csv, neo4j, load, neo4j-desktop

I have a CSV file I generate through code. I want to import the generated CSV file into neo4j using the following cypher query.

```
 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:////Users/{user}/Desktop/neo4j-importer/tmp/temp_data.csv'
```

I have changed the following config varables

Commenting out `dbms.directories.import=import`.
And set `dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true`

Problem is I get thrown the following error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed: 
Couldn't load the external resource at: 
file:/Users/{user}/Library/Application%20Support/Neo4j%20Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-c517b267-220d-4b7a-be26-813d5b64a51a/installation-3.5.3/import/Users/{user}/Desktop/neo4j-importer/tmp/temp_data.csv
```

I mean it is partly right just not the `/Users/{user}/Library/Application%20Support/Neo4j%20Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-c517b267-220d-4b7a-be26-813d5b64a51a/installation-3.5.3/import/` bit... Any suggestions on how to fix this weird file pathing problem?

Comment: It means the file is not found.  You may put the file: temp_data.csv in folder 'import' then execute your cypher again.

Comment: This is a potential solution. 
Do you have a method to dynamically detect the new database file that is generated each time a graph.db is spun up? as the import file resides inside it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the config setting to point to the directory with your imports:

```
dbms.directories.import=/Users/{user}/Desktop/neo4j-importer/tmp
```

and then changing the Cypher query to just specify the CSV file:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///temp_data.csv'
...
```

Comment: I've tried this and the default file location "import" is still used

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the config?